# Panda Query Error with Terminal Menu String

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

This is a simple example from a more complex python script I'm writing, but this shows the essential problem I hope I can get help on.

I have a list that I'm putting in a dataframe, like this:

```
data={'Name':['Tom', 'Bob', 'Karen', 'Bill', 'Stefan', 'Jack', 'Bob', 'Debbie'],
        'Points':[20,23,41, 17, 24, 7, 52, 60]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to filter this list and so I have this string that I use with df.query

```
strQ='Name=="Tom" or Name=="Bob"'
df=df.query(strQ)
```

This gives the results exactly as expected.

Here is where I'm running into the problem.  I'm using simple_term_menu so I can chose the names I want to filter rather than hard coding the names.
Here is the code for this:

```
arrTemp=['Tom', 'Bob', 'Karen', 'Bill', 'Stefan', 'Jack', 'Debbie']
terminal_menu = TerminalMenu(arrTemp,
    multi_select=True,
    show_multi_select_hint=True,
)
menu_entry_indices = terminal_menu.show()

queryStr = ' or '.join([f'Name=="{v}"' for  v in terminal_menu.chosen_menu_entries])
queryStr= "'{}'".format(queryStr)
```

The resulting queryStr is a type 'string' and if I print it out, after choosing Tom and Bob, the result is this:

```
queryStr='Name=="Tom" or Name=="Bob"'
```

queryStr is exactly the same as strQ above

But when if I put this string into the df.query

```
subs = df.query(queryStr)
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'Name=="Tom" or Name=="Bob"'
```

I've tried various ways to fix this and searched the web but nothing works.  I was hoping someone could help here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the line:
queryStr= "'{}'".format(queryStr)

was causing the problem.  Once this is deleted it works as expected